# jQuery file uploader and turbolinks not working on heroku, have tried every fix I can find on SO

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks-5

I have spent hours trying to fix this. I used the Heroku guide for S3 Direct upload in Rails. I was able to get it working in my customized version. Works great in the local setup but not on Heroku. I have narrowed it down to a JS problem because the progress bar  does not want to load. The JS makes the upload depend on the creation of the  before it will start the upload. My JS skills suck (I keep plugging along because I have to but I hate JS with a passion, it's just not for me).

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery-table
//= require js/stellar
//= require js/nivo-lightbox.min
//= require js/custom
//= require js/css3-animate-it
//= require gritter
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
// = require_tree .
```

To get it to work in test I had to put the script in the form itself.

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center inner">

    <%= form_for(@repair, html: { class: "directUpload", data: { 'form-data' => (@s3_direct_post.fields), 'url' => @s3_direct_post.url, 'host' => URI.parse(@s3_direct_post.url).host } }) do |f| %>
      <% if @repair.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@repair.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this repair from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @repair.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

        <div class="field h3">
          <%= current_user.email %>
        </div>
        <div class="field h3">
          <%= f.label 'PPE Serial #' %>
          <%= f.collection_select :ppe_id, current_user.ppes, :id, :serial %>
        </div>
        <div class="field h4">
          <%= "Entered On: #{Date.today}" %><br />
        </div>
        <div class="field h4" id="photoUploader" >
          <%= f.fields_for :photos, @repair.photos.build do |photos_fields| %>
          <%= photos_fields.label :file_url, 'Upload a Photo' %>
          <%= photos_fields.file_field :file_url %>
          <% end %>
          <div class='progress' id='pgbar'></div>
        </div>
        <div class="field h4">
          <%= f.label :notes, 'Please give a detailed description of repairs needed.' %><br />
          <%= f.text_area :notes, class: 'note_area' %>
        </div>


        <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Save Record', class: 'btn btn-brand' %>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(window).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
                $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
                    var fileInput    = $(elem);
                    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
                    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
                    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
                    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress' id='pgbar'></div>").append(progressBar);
                    $('#pgbar').remove();
                    fileInput.after(barContainer);
                    fileInput.fileupload({
                        fileInput:       fileInput,
                        url:             form.data('url'),
                        type:            'POST',
                        autoUpload:       true,
                        formData:         form.data('form-data'),
                        paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
                        dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
                        replaceFileInput: false,
                        progressall: function (e, data) {
                            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                            progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
                        },
                        start: function (e) {
                            submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

                            progressBar.
                            css('background', 'green').
                            css('display', 'block').
                            css('width', '0%').
                            text("Loading...");
                        },
                        done: function(e, data) {
                            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
                            progressBar.text("Uploading done");

                            // extract key and generate URL from response
                            var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
                            var url   = '//' + form.data('host') + '/' + key;

                            // create hidden field
                            var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
                            form.append(input);
                        },
                        fail: function(e, data) {
                            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

                            progressBar.
                            css("background", "red").
                            text("Failed");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

      <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried having the script in the application.js file, with mixed results in test but none work on Heroku. I have also tried every combination of

```
$(window).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

$(Document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

$(document).ready(function(){

$(function(){
```

I've precompiled assets, I've disabled turbolinks for this form, disabled turbo links for this page, disabled turbolinks for this entire app, moved the order of the files in the appplication.js require list.

I wish I understood the JS better to tweak the upload script so it didn't depend on what ever it seems to depend upon to load.

I'm getting no errors in the JS console. It just loads or it doesn't depending on the environment.

Any help is much appreciated.

One note on the JS for the progress bar. In my working version on Test, turbolinks would keep creating the container div for the bar on reload. So empty bars were being created but they didn't interfere with the script at all. So I created the div then added a call to remove it so that if it exists already it would be replaced by the new one on reload.

Comment: My initial thought is that turbolinks is not loading the script "on turbolinks load" unless you are directly on that page on turbolinks load (so you can't click there from another page). Otherwise, the  '.directUpload' is not on the page yet, and therefore it's not binding. This would make sense since it works when you put it on the page directly - meaning it loads every time that page loads.

Comment: It works perfect no matter how you come at it on the test version. I get that something is not loading. I can click it 8 ways to Sunday in test, works perfect every time. Nothing has worked so far on Heroku. As I mentioned above I have tried having the code in various places and have tried many iterations (seriously like 50 different combos) of code and turbo links on/off with no success. I'm looking for someone to maybe weigh in on a better structure for that script as I think it has something to do with how it's crafted.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to work around this. The problem was not with my JS code in the upload script on the page, but the fact that Heroku refused to include the jQuery-uploader code no matter what I tried. Like I said, works great in production, but not at all on Heroku. What I did to load the `jQuery-upload/basic JS` into my Heroku install was to copy the three files in the jQuery-upload gem  into my /public folder then add this to my initializer file for assets:

/config/initializers/assets.rb:

```
... #added code:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery-fileupload/basic-plus.js )
```

Not sure why, no matter what I did, the JS code that would load without any issue

Now when Heroku boots it loads that JS into my application.js file. Everything is working great. I have to wonder if there isn't some flaw in the gem.